# Email validation. Working when accessed from the website, but fails the unit test

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii2

I encountered a rather strange problem today.

I've set up a model with these rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['name', 'email', 'website'], 'required'],
        [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 512],
        [['name'], 'unique'],
        [['email'], 'email'],
        [['website'], 'url'],
    ];
}
```

This is working accordingly when accessed via the Controller. However my unit 
test failes on validating the email:

```
    $model->email = 'somethinghan.nl';
    $this->assertFalse($model->validate('email'),
        'Email is invalid.');
    $model->email = 'student@han.nl';
    $this->assertTrue($model->validate('email'),
        'Validating email with a valid email: ' . $model->email);
```

I've used the same email in the form, where the data is admitted to the database as it should. But when used here, is fails on the second email validation.

I've tried other email formats, but that won't solve the problem either. Any ideas?

Comment: and how does look *model validate* method?

Comment: @venca that is Yii's method

Comment: @Wijnand does it return false or it throws an error?

Comment: Try to dump model variable and post the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would dump the errors with [`getErrors()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#getErrors()-detail) you would see it's not the email validation that fails.

The reason it doesn't work is because you don't specify the attributes to validate as an array:

If you look in the [`Validator`-code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/validators/Validator.php#L230) (where the `validate()`-call eventually ends up):

```
public function validateAttributes($model, $attributes = null)
{
    if (is_array($attributes)) {
        $attributes = array_intersect($this->attributes, $attributes);
    } else {
        $attributes = $this->attributes;
    }
    ...
}
```

So basically: If it's not an array it gets thrown out, so it validates all attributes.

Change it to `$this->assertFalse($model->validate(['email']), 'Email is invalid.');` and it should work

Edit: BTW, this is a very easy mistake to make, since the framework **does** convert a single string into an array in a lot of other places. So this behavior is not really consistent.